# Не изменяя тело и аргументы функции f, сделайте так, чтобы при её вызове из объекта data выводились данные

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как не изменяя тело и аргументы функции f, сделать так, чтобы при её вызове из объекта data выводились данные.

```js
function f() {
  console.log(this.success);
}

const data = { success: 'Успех - он тут!' };

// код

f();
```

Comment: А зачем это? И что это?

Comment: Это задание с явным указанием this

Comment: `f= f.bind(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией bind

```js
function f() {
  console.log(this.success);
}

const data = { success: 'Успех - он тут!' };

f = f.bind(data)

f();
```

Answer (score 1):

нашел решение на https://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply

f.call(data)

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]